# Why does this generator work with a for loop but not with next()?

Tags: python-3.x, generator, yield

I am trying to make a generator that gives me the permutations of 3 numbers

```
def generador():
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                yield i,j,k
```

with a for loop `for a,b,c in generador():` it work's just fine but:

```
for _ in range(27):
    print(next(generador()))
```

just prints `(0,0,0)` over an over again. Why?

Comment: There's a function in the standard library that can do this for you by the way [`list(itertools.product(range(3), range(3), range(3)))`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: You get this error because `generator()` creates the generator. So you're creating the generator and getting its first item 27 times. The correct way would be to create it once `my_gen = generator()` and then you can call next on it `for _ in range(27): print(next(my_gen))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to latch the generator to a variable and `next` through that so youre going through the same instance, otherwise you're going through a new instance each loop, hence you're getting 0,0,0

```
def generador():
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                yield i,j,k
a = generador()
for _ in range(27):
    print(next(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

Like has been said you’re creating the generator each iteration. You need iterate over it each iteration:

```
gen = generador()
for _ in range(27):
    print(next(gen))
```

Although `itertools.product` will do exactly this for you:

```
def generador():
    yield from itertools.product(range(3), repeat=3)
```